# Shell script to execute executable over numerous files

Tags: shell

Hi I have a file that sorts some code and reformats it. I have over 200 files to apply this to with incremental names run001, run002 etc. Is there a quick way to write a shell script to execute this file over all the files? The executable creates a new file called run001an etc so just running over all files containing run doesnt work, how do i increment the file number?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
for i in ./run*; do
  process_the_file $i
done
```

which is valid Bash/Ksh

Answer (score 0):

To be more specific with `run###` files you can have

```
for file in dir/run[0-9][0-9][0-9]; do
    do_something "$file"
done
```

`dir` could simply be just . or other directories. If they have spaces, quote them around `""` but only the directory parts.

In bash, you can make use of extended patterns to generate all number matches not just 3 digits:

```
shopt -s extglob

for file in dir/run+([0-9]); do
    do_something "$file"
done
```